# How to accurately store geolocation data, filter within a radius, and calculate distance?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I write new locations with:

`ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), 4326)`

They get saved under `"profile".location`:

`SRID=4326;POINT(-75.1234 35.1234)`

I try to filter profiles within some `:radius` in meters where `:ownLocation` is some location string that consists of a bunch of numbers:

`ST_DWithin("profile".location, :ownLocation::geometry, :radius)`

Then when I get the results back and calculate their distance with:
`ST_Distance(
ST_Transform("profile".location::geometry, 3857::int), ST_Transform(:ownLocation::geometry, 3857::int)
) as distance`

and convert the distance from meters to miles,  my results are a bit off. Let's say I set a max radius of within 10 miles -  the distance I get back seems anywhere from 0-23 miles (would expect 0-10 miles).

I am wondering where I am going wrong here, and have a feeling it may have to do with projections, or I am using the functions incorrectly.

---

Update after solution: store as `4326`, display distance as `3857`

store as `4326`:

`ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), 4326)`

filter using `geography` type so it can accept filter radius as meters that users will pass in:

`ST_DWithin("profile".location::geography, :ownLocation::geography, :radiusInMeters)`

display distance from `4326` to `3857` meters with correction (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html):

```
ST_Distance(
ST_Transform("profile".location::geometry, 3857),
ST_Transform(:ownLocation::geometry, 3857)
) * cosd(42.3521) as distance
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3857 is not suitable for computing distances, as it introduces important distortions as you move away from the equator.

Instead, you can use `ST_Distance` using the `geography` datatype:

```
ST_Distance("profile".location::geography,:ownLocation::geography) as distance
```

Regarding `st_dwithin`, it uses the projection unit, which is degrees, not meters. You can also use the `geography` datatype here.

Comment: Is there a better alternative to `ST_DWithin` that uses meters? I am trying to filter "get profiles within 10 miles of your own location", where users will pass in the radius as either miles/km, so I'd rather work with meters rather than degrees (unless it's just as simple to convert?).

Comment: It would be wrong to convert degrees to meters (a degree of latitude has not the same ground length as a degree of longitude). You can either use another projection that preserves the distances (like UTM), or rely on the geography datatype as distances will be returned in meters

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. So `ST_DWithin` is compatible with meters as long as you pass in `geography` type: `boolean ST_DWithin(geometry g1, geometry g2, double precision distance_of_srid)` vs.
`boolean ST_DWithin(geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters)` So I should be using `geography` type everywhere, but could you clarify if I should be saving my points as `4326` or should I switch to something else? It sounds like I shouldn't save them as `3857` because it's not good for distances?

Comment: They all have their advantages and limitations. 3857 is very common for representation. You would have to assess your needs and the "cost" associated to each of your requirement in the various projection / geography, then find the optimal one. Check this [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry)

Comment: Ok, thanks! With your hints I made some updates (shown in the original question) that seems to give me the results I would expect. http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/4326-vs-3857 mentions `(Fun fact: This is why we store data in EPSG:4326, but display it in EPSG:3857!)` and https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html shows a correction to give me something I'm happy with.

Answer (score 1):

The unit of EPSG 4326 is degrees whereas the unit of EPSG 3857 is meters.

ST_DWithin("profile".location, :ownLocation::geometry, :radius) will take degrees as radius not meters or miles.

Transform "profile".location and :ownLocation::geometry to 3857 should work;